# Office 365 force GAL update

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

We were working on importing some employee data into AD yesterday (including mobile numbers) and we incorrectly thought that the mobile attribute was turned off in Azure Sync. Turns out it was not and the mobile numbers were synced to 365 and into the GAL.

This caused a bit of an employee privacy issue, so now I am trying to resolve it.

As a quick solution, I wiped all of the mobile numbers from AD and forced an Azure Sync. If I go into a mailbox in 365 Admin center the mobile number is gone. If I check Delve, the mobile number is gone. But in the local Outlook GAL they are all still there.

I have already tried running `Get-AddressList -Identity "All Users"` to force a GAL update, but no luck.
Its been 16 hours since I removed the mobile numbers.

What are my options for getting these out of the GAL?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can force the OAB update with Office365. 
Even if you did, you cannot force the clients to update - it takes up to 24 hours after an OAB generation before it is picked up by the clients. Clients only download the OAB once a day by default, or when Outlook is restarted - that behaviour cannot be changed. Your only option is to force a download via the Send/Receive menu.

Comment: Thanks. I have restarted my own Outlook client and done send/receive with no update of the OAB, so I was assuming the issue is still the GAL on the exchange side.

Comment: Clients are finally starting to update now.